# 'reloadAction' in Microsoft Bot Framework 3.15 for Node.js is not passing on 'dialogArgs'

Tags: node.js, botframework

I'm following the example from the Bot Framework pages, under 'Handle User Actions' (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-actions?view=azure-bot-service-3.0)

```
// Order dinner.
bot.dialog('orderDinner', [
    function(session, args, next){
        if(args && args.isReloaded){
            // Reload action was triggered.
        }

        session.send("Lets order some dinner!");
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Dinner menu:", dinnerMenu);
    }
    //...other waterfall steps...
])
// Once triggered, will restart the dialog.
.reloadAction('startOver', 'Ok, starting over.', {
    matches: /^start over$/i,
    dialogArgs: {
        isReloaded: true;
    }
});
```

and after reloading the dialog `args.isReloaded`is always `undefined`.  That is, it doesn't seem that the framework is passing through what is put in `dialogArgs`.  Any clues as to what I might be missing?  I'm using v 3.15 (or rather, the people for whom I'm working are using 3.15) -- was this something that was introduced in a later version 3, that is, after 3.5?  Or is something just going wrong?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Tried the code with the specified version and is working correctly. There is an errant ";" in your code (which is also in the docs) that should be removed and may be the culprit. Change the following line to the below.

Hope of help!

```js
dialogArgs: {
  isReloaded: true
}
```

Comment: The `reloadAction` works fine for me (indeed, I had detected that erroneous ';' as well), it's that the `isReloaded` is not being passed to the first waterfall step of my dialog on reload.  It is for you?  That is ```module.exports = function () {

    this.bot.dialog('/orderDinner', [
        function (session, args, next) {
            logger.info('was reloaded', args)``` shows that `args` are `{"resumed":4}` after the dialog is reloaded.  Am I missing something conceptually?